# playing a looping sound when button is pressed in android

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

my problem is a simple one.  i want to play a looping sound only when a button is pressed.  the following are the switch statement and if else approaches i've tried. at best, i can play the sound but it won't pause when the button is no longer pressed.

```
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
 MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.clash);

 if (v.getId() == R.id.clash && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
  mp.setLooping(true);
  mp.start();

 }else if (v.getId() == R.id.clash && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
 {mp.pause();

 }
}

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.clash);

     switch (event.getAction()){

     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
      mp.setLooping(true);
      mp.start();

     case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
      mp.pause();
    }


    return false;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returning `true` instead of `false` at the end of `onTouch`.

What's (probably) happening right now is that you get an `ACTION_DOWN` event which starts your sound. By returning `false` you tell the framework that you **did not** consume the action, which it takes to mean that you will not consume future actions, either. Thus, it will stop sending touch events to your view.

Relevant quote from [android-developers](http://markmail.org/message/obavsolbw37smlxu):

> When you get the ACTION_DOWN event,
>   are you returning true? If not, this
>   is probably the issue. The framework
>   will only deliver future touch events
>   (ACTION_MOVEs and the ACTION_UP) to
>   that View if its touch listener or
>   onTouchEvent returns true.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  i did switch to true but i still have the same problem.

Comment: @Puzzled: Can you see `ACTION_DOWN` being fired in logcat? Is this a custom view? I just noticed that your `onTouch` method doesn't appear to be an override.

Comment: the logcat is completely blank.  i have no idea why but i never see anything in it.  this is not a custom view.  just a simple button.

Comment: i found out why the logcat was blank.  here's the complete log.  and no, it isn't showing ACTION_DOWN being fired.

Answer (score 0):

Move your mp outside the onTouch Handler!

```
MediaPlayer mp;
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.clash);

 switch (event.getAction()){

 case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
  mp.setLooping(true);
  mp.start();

 case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
  mp.pause();
}
```

Comment: Error : Missing return statement !